# GOanda on github for Oanda API Rest in GoLang

Tags: go

When I try to install this package:

```
go get github.com/jasonnfls/goanda
```

I get this error:

> /usr/local/go/bin/src/github.com/jasonnfls/goanda/trade.go:47: cannot use responseObj (type UpdateTradeResponse) as type OrderResponse in return argument

What would be the best way to resolve this?

Anyone have a good solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug in the package appears to be a copy/paste error. In the file `trade.go`, change the return value on line 20 from `OrderResponse` to `UpdateTradeResponse`, then run `go install github.com/jasonnfls/goanda`.

The file will be in your `$GOPATH/src/github.com/jasonnfls/goanda`

I submitted a pull request with the fix to the repo owner.

Comment: Thank you!  That worked!  Now I just haft to figure out how to make a working example calling the functions!

Comment: Glad I could help. As this answered the question as is, would you please click to accept the answer? As far as using the library, it looks like everything is based off using a `Client`, so simply call `NewFxTradeClient` or `NewFxPracticeClient` to get a new `Client`, then start using it.

Comment: What I am currently trying to figure out right now is how to populate Client and pass it too NewFxTradeClient.  Kind of like Ansi C but not.  Not like perl/php so I am trying to get a working example!

Comment: I don't know what you mean. You pass those functions a string (whatever your `token` is), and they return a `Client` all ready to go. The statement `client := goanda.NewFxTradeClient("mytoken")` would compile and run, but that obviously isn't a real token.

Comment: When I go to populate Client what you are calling "mytoken" I get undefined: Client    package main

  import "github.com/jasonnfls/goanda"

  func main() {
        account := Client{Token: "This is API key token", Env: 1234567890, client: "unknown at this time what goes here"}
        oanda := goanda.NewFxTradeClient(&account)
  }

Comment: Those `New...` functions populate it for you.

Comment: This code runs https://play.golang.org/p/o6SeJuFzII (copy paste locally. you can't import external libs on the playground). Have you done the golang tour? https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1

Comment: If you want to refer to the `Client` struct manually, you have to specify it by the package name e.g. `goanda.Client`. It doesn't get passed into the `New` functions, it is returned from them. If you create it manually yourself, you don't need to call either of the `New` functions.

Comment: My issues is populating the type of Client on lines 7 to 10 in goanda/client.go.  Setting the 3 values of Token / Env / client so I can make the mytoken to pass to that function!

Comment: This is a library for the oanda REST API. The `token` is just a string. You presumably get the API token from https://www.oanda.com/ . You do not need to manually create the `Client`, just pass your API token into the `New` function.

Comment: cannot use account (type goanda.Client) as type string in argument to goanda.NewFxTradeClient when I use this to set the values //account := goanda.Client{Token: "This is API key token", Env: "1234567890", client: "unknown at this time what goes here"}
 10         account := goanda.Client{Token: "This is API key token", Env: "1234567890"}....  The token is 2 values one API key and one Account # that is how oanda takes the arguments.  How to feed that into go type I am not sure

Comment: Well, then maybe this isn't the right library? Or perhaps you shouldn't use the `New` functions? The value to put in the third slot of `oanda.Client` is `http.DefaultClient` after importing `net/http`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in the package. It contains invalid code.

The solution would be to use an older version that isn't broken (if there is one), fix the bug, or get someone else (perhaps the author) to fix the bug.